# Does a phrase exist that one uses to another person who is about to sneeze?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

"Bless you" or "God bless you" are commonly used **after** a sneeze but does one exist (or was one once commonly used but no longer) when a person is obviously **about to** sneeze?

Comment: None that I know of - this seems like a very niche use and whenever I squint at something, people think I'm about to sneeze. Might get confusing.

Comment: I say Bless you for fun WHILE they sneeze if I see they are about to

Comment: Light is a common sneezing trigger

Comment: Get out your hanky!

Comment: I used to tell my kids, **"cover your mouth"**! Pretty consistently. Enough to make it common. I, too, say *Bless you* before people sneeze.

Comment: I say... "You are so good looking."  before or after.

Comment: I've said "boo", which can scare them out of the sneeze. Very frustrating. A children's book (Where Did I Come From?) uses a "great big sneeze" to explain to young children what an orgasm feels like.

Comment: Ugh. The author of that book must not be of the poor few of us who dread sneezes as they make us ache.

Comment: "Point that thing some place else".

Comment: "Sneeze if you love me!"

Answer (score 1):

> [Gesundheit! Sneezing Gets A Big
>   Reaction](http://www.nytimes.com/1983/06/22/garden/gesundheit-sneezing-gets-a-big-reaction.html)
>
> As a child with various minor allergies, I used to sneeze quite often.
>   Each time she heard me sneeze, my grandmother would quickly bless me
>   with ''zum leben un gesund'' (to life and health) and pull up on my
>   right ear. **Upon the inevitable second sneeze, my left ear would be
>   pulled, accompanied by another blessing, ''zum wachsen un kwelln'' (to
>   grow and thrive)**.

As the act of sneezing was associated with death, there are likely many 'old wives' expressions.  The children's rhyme "Ring Around the Rosie" addresses the link between  a plague death and sneezing:

- Ring-a-ring o' roses,
  A pocket full of posies,
  **A-tishoo! A-tishoo!**
  We all fall down.

Wikipedia list over 80 languages for [Responses to sneezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responses_to_sneezing#List_of_responses_in_other_languages), and whereas some include different blessings/health terms for the second or third sneeze, none are 'preventative'

Comment: I think your grandmother just enjoyed pulling on your ears.

Comment: The link is from a NY Times story -not mine